# on input ТОЛЬКО для ввода текста

Tags: javascript, jquery, input

```
$("input").on("input", function(e) {
  console.log("input");
});
```

если на введу значение в инпут, вызовется этот метод. если я нажму backspace - вызоветсья этот метод.

как сделать чтобы при удалении символа метод он инпут не вызывался

Comment: `$("input").on("keyup", function(e) { if (e.keyCode=="8") {return;} else { console.log("input"); } });`

Comment: А что Ваш метод должен делать?